# PHP Restrict Access by date

Tags: php, sql

I have two variables: `$current_date` and `$last_payment_date`.

`$current_date` is today's day and `$last_payment_date` is a date which 2 weeks later `date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+2 week"));`.

**What I need?**

If user will try to access the page then PHP will check if DATA ALREADY EXISTS OR NOT.

If data is already exists then, check Today's date and what is value of `$last_payment_date`

If today's date is less then Or equal the value of variable last_payment_date THEN USER WILL CAN'T ACCESS

but today's date is greater then the value of variable last_payment_date THEN USER WILL CONTINUE ACCESS THE PAGE

Comment: first of all, your date should be 'Y-m-d', not 'd/m/Y'

Comment: @luweiqi: Thank You for formatting my question

Comment: @Your Common Sense please tell me HOW TO DO THIS **If today's date is less then Or equal the value of variable last_payment_date THEN USER WILL CAN'T ACCESS** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

> If user will try to access the page then PHP will check if DATA ALREADY EXISTS OR NOT.

```
if(isset($current_date, $last_payment_date)) {

} else echo "You cannot access this page";
```

> If data is already exists then, check Today's date and what is value of $last_payment_date
>
> If today's date is less then Or equal the value of variable last_payment_date THEN USER WILL CAN'T ACCESS
>
> but today's date is greater then the value of variable last_payment_date THEN USER WILL CONTINUE ACCESS THE PAGE

```
if(strtotime('now') <= strtotime($last_payment_date)) {

} else echo "You cannot access this page";
```

---

So, when put together, your code should be:

```
if(isset($current_date, $last_payment_date)) {

    if(strtotime('now') <= strtotime($last_payment_date)) {
    // code if user is able to access the page
    } else echo "You cannot access this page";

} else echo "You cannot access this page";
```

Comment: I selecting date using `$timezone = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$current_date = date('d/m/Y');`

Comment: I trying this codes but not working: `if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1){
     
     if(strtotime($current_date) <= strtotime($payent_due_date)) {
          echo "Ok";
      } else{
       echo "<div class='w3-container w3-section w3-red w3-card-16'>
                      <h1 style='text-align:center;'>!Error Found</h1>
                      <h3 style='text-align:center;'>Bill Already Exists</h3>
             <h3 style='text-align:center;'>So You Can't Generate Bill Again</h3>
                      </div>";
       echo "You cannot access this page";
       exit();  
      }
       }`

Comment: I selecting date using `$timezone = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); $current_date = date('d/m/Y'); `
 
I trying this codes but not working: `if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1){ if(strtotime($current_date) <= strtotime($payent_due_date)) { echo "Ok"; } else{ echo "<div class='w3-container w3-section w3-red w3-card-16'> <h1 style='text-align:center;'>!Error Found</h1> <h3 style='text-align:center;'>Bill Already Exists</h3> <h3 style='text-align:center;'>So You Can't Generate Bill Again</h3> </div>"; echo "You cannot access this page"; exit(); } } ` ** Please do support me

Comment: @GourabMazumder You need to set the time zone using: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`, no need to assign to `$timezone`

Comment: No SQL OR PHP ERROR . I just reciving error: `echo "<div class='w3-container w3-section w3-red w3-card-16'>
                      <h1 style='text-align:center;'>!Error Found</h1>
                      <h3 style='text-align:center;'>Bill Already Exists</h3>
             <h3 style='text-align:center;'>So You Can't Generate Bill Again</h3>
                      </div>";
       echo "You cannot access this page";
       exit();  `

Comment: Please tell me about fix the error: `if(strtotime($current_date) <= strtotime($last_payment_date)) { echo "Ok"; } else{ echo "<div class='w3-container w3-section w3-red w3-card-16'> <h1 style='text-align:center;'>!Error Found</h1> <h3 style='text-align:center;'>Bill Already Exists</h3> <h3 style='text-align:center;'>So You Can't Generate Bill Again</h3> </div>"; echo "You cannot access this page"; exit(); }

Comment: @GourabMazumder You spelt `$payent_due_date` wrongly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108739/discussion-between-gourab-mazumder-and-luweiqi).